# Only show posts from a certain category?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, loop

How can I only show items from a certain category (category 51)?

Here's my loop below that I need to incorporate the code into.

```
<div class="news-content-inner">
  <?php $portfolioloop = new WP_Query( array( 'paged' => get_query_var('paged'), 'post_type' => 'news', 'posts_per_page' => 4 ) ); ?>
  <?php while ( $portfolioloop->have_posts() ) : $portfolioloop->the_post(); ?>
  <div class="news-item" onClick="location.href='<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>'">
    <h2><a style="color:#F45B11!IMPORTANT;" href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo the_time('d.m.Y'); ?> / <?php echo the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <p class="news-page">
      <?php if (get_field('description') != "") { ?>
      <?php echo the_field('description'); ?>
        <?php } else { 
        $newscontent = get_the_content();
        $newscontent_str = strip_tags($newscontent, '');
        echo substr($newscontent_str,0,250) . "…";
        } ?>
    </p>
  </div>
  <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
  <p class="news-page" style="font-size:12px!IMPORTANT;"><?php echo wp_count_posts('news')->publish; ?> opportunities</p>
    <?php if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) {
    wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $portfolioloop ) ); } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify your `WP_Query` loop. Add a `tax_query` argument to filter the category you want.

```
$portfolioloop = new WP_Query(array(
    'paged'          => get_query_var('paged'),
    'post_type'      => 'news',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'tax_query'      => array(
        // Note: tax_query expects an array of arrays!
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'portfolio', // my guess
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => 51,
        ),
    ),
));
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: Thanks, that worked great. The only thing that's not quite right is the wp_count_posts bit at the bottom. It's counted the total number of posts instead of the number of posts that are within the category. How can I change that?

Comment: @Rob: try `$portfolioloop->post_count`

Comment: You're welcome. To get the total number of posts (regardless of pagination) use `$portfolioloop->found_posts`.

Comment: Ok great, didn't know that.